# Splitting full address column in multiple columns

Tags: r, split, tidyr, stringr

I have a dataframe with the following column structure (over 1000+ rows total):

```
addressfull
POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||molengraaf 20, 1689 GL Utrecht, Netherlands||15||map
POINT(3.124537680 32.179354014)||DEF_32||winkellaan 67, 5788 BG Amsterdam, Netherlands||13||map
POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||vermeerstraat 18, 0932 DC Rotterdam, Netherlands||11||map
POINT(2.915206183 24.315583523)||DEF_32||--||13||map
POINT (2.900824999999923 34.3175721)||DEF_84||Zandhorstlaan 122, 0823 GT Ochtrup, Germany||17||map
```

```
structure(list(addressfull = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("POINT (2.900824999999923 34.3175721)||DEF_84||Zandhorstlaan 122, 0823 GT Ochtrup, Germany||17||map", 
"POINT(2.915206183 24.315583523)||DEF_32||--||13||map", "POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||molengraaf 20, 1689 GL Utrecht, Netherlands||15||map", 
"POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||vermeerstraat 18, 0932 DC Rotterdam, Netherlands||11||map", 
"POINT(3.124537680 32.179354014)||DEF_32||winkellaan 67, 5788 BG Amsterdam, Netherlands||13||map"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

The column contains an location, street, housenumber, zip code, city, and country. I want to split the column addressfull with R in multiple columns, as example:

```
street        house number      zip       city      country
molengraaf    20                1689 GL   Utrecht   Netherlands
winkellaan    67                5788 BG   Amsterdam Netherlands
vermeerstraat 18                0932 DC   Rotterdam Netherlands
na            na                na        na        na
Zandhorstlaan 122               0823 GT   Ochtrup   Germany
```

I have readed the tidyr and stringr documentation. I can see an pattern for splitting (by ")", "| from position x", and ",". but i can't figure out the correct code to split the column into multiple columns.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Look into `tidyr` separate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `stringr`solution is this:

```
addresssplit <- data.frame(
  street = str_extract(addressfull$addressfull, "(?<=DEF_\\d{2}\\|\\|)\\w+\\b"),
  number = str_extract(addressfull$addressfull, "\\d{1,}(?=,)"),
  zip = str_extract(addressfull$addressfull, "(?<=\\s)\\d{4}\\s[A-Z]{2}"),
  city = str_extract(addressfull$addressfull, "(?<=\\d{4}\\s[A-Z]{2}\\s)\\w+"),
  country = str_extract(addressfull$addressfull, "(?<=[a-z]\\b,\\s)\\w+\\b")
)
```

RESULT:

```
addresssplit
         street number     zip      city     country
1    molengraaf     20 1689 GL   Utrecht Netherlands
2    winkellaan     67 5788 BG Amsterdam Netherlands
3 vermeerstraat     18 0932 DC Rotterdam Netherlands
4          <NA>   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>        <NA>
5 Zandhorstlaan    122 0823 GT   Ochtrup     Germany
```

DATA:

```
addressfull <- structure(list(addressfull = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("POINT (2.900824999999923 34.3175721)||DEF_84||Zandhorstlaan 122, 0823 GT Ochtrup, Germany||17||map", 
                                                                                    "POINT(2.915206183 24.315583523)||DEF_32||--||13||map", "POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||molengraaf 20, 1689 GL Utrecht, Netherlands||15||map", 
                                                                                    "POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||vermeerstraat 18, 0932 DC Rotterdam, Netherlands||11||map", 
                                                                                    "POINT(3.124537680 32.179354014)||DEF_32||winkellaan 67, 5788 BG Amsterdam, Netherlands||13||map"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                           -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could brute force it using `sub` for a base R approach:

```
df$steet <- sub("^(\\S+)\\s+.*$", "\\1", df$adressfull)
df$`house number` <- sub("^\\S+\\s+(\\d+).*$", "\\1", df$adressfull)
df$zip <- sub("^\\S+\\s+\\d+,\\s*(\\d+\\s+[A-Z]+).*$", "\\1", df$adressfull)
df$city <- sub("^.*?(\\S+),\\s*\\S+$", "\\1", df$adressfull)
df$country <- sub("^.*,\\s*(\\S+)$", "\\1", df$adressfull)
df

                                   adressfull      steet house number     zip
1 molengraaf 20, 1689 GL Utrecht, Netherlands molengraaf           20 1689 GL
     city     country
1 Utrecht Netherlands
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(adressfull=c("molengraaf 20, 1689 GL Utrecht, Netherlands"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This assumes that we have already isolated just the address text.  To do that, conisder:

```
text <- "POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||molengraaf 20, 1689 GL Utrecht, Netherlands||15||map"
addresfull <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\\|\\|"))[3]
addresfull

[1] "molengraaf 20, 1689 GL Utrecht, Netherlands"
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a tidyverse approach to the problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(addressfull = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("POINT (2.900824999999923 34.3175721)||DEF_84||Zandhorstlaan 122, 0823 GT Ochtrup, Germany||17||map", 
                                                                               "POINT(2.915206183 24.315583523)||DEF_32||--||13||map", "POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||molengraaf 20, 1689 GL Utrecht, Netherlands||15||map", 
                                                                               "POINT(3.124537653 32.179354012)||DEF_32||vermeerstraat 18, 0932 DC Rotterdam, Netherlands||11||map", 
                                                                               "POINT(3.124537680 32.179354014)||DEF_32||winkellaan 67, 5788 BG Amsterdam, Netherlands||13||map"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                           -5L))



df %>% separate(addressfull, sep = "\\|\\|", into = c("Coords", "DEF", "ADDRESS"),extra = "drop") %>% 
  select(ADDRESS) %>% 
  separate(ADDRESS, sep = ",", into = c("street", "city", "country")) %>% 
  separate(street, sep = "(?= \\d)", into = c("street", "house_number")) %>% 
  separate(city, sep = "(?<=[A-Z][A-Z])", into = c("zip", "city"))
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [4].
#> Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [4].
#>          street house_number      zip       city      country
#> 1    molengraaf           20  1689 GL    Utrecht  Netherlands
#> 2    winkellaan           67  5788 BG  Amsterdam  Netherlands
#> 3 vermeerstraat           18  0932 DC  Rotterdam  Netherlands
#> 4            --         <NA>     <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
#> 5 Zandhorstlaan          122  0823 GT    Ochtrup      Germany
```

Created on 2020-02-27 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)